# How can i hitTesObject a movieclip inside a movieclip AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want my zombie to collect the brains(g1b1,g1b2,g1b3,g1b4). These brains are inside my movieclip 'platform1' because i need it to have a scrolling background effect. Well my zombie character can walk however he can't collect the brains.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class z extends MovieClip {

    private var score:int=0;
    private var zombieSpeed:int=7; //speed for zombie
    private var gravity:int=1;
    private var jumpSpeed:int=0;//current speed for the jump
    private var jumpSpeedLimit:int=15; //how quick the jump

    private var jump, left, right, down, mainJump:Boolean=false; //zombie is not jumping

    public function z() {

    }

    public function Game1() {
        stop();
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
        zombie.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCharacter1);
        gamePlay1();
    }

    private function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.LEFT) {
            left=true;
            zombie.gotoAndPlay("left");
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT) {
            right=true;
            zombie.gotoAndPlay("right");
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE || Keyboard.UP) {
            jump=true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.DOWN) {
            down=true;
        }
    }

    private function keyReleased(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.LEFT || Keyboard.D) {
            left=false;
            zombieSpeed-=5;
            zombie.gotoAndStop("idleLeft");
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT || Keyboard.A) {
            right=false;
            zombieSpeed+=5;
            zombie.gotoAndStop("idleRight");
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE || Keyboard.UP || Keyboard.W) {
            jump=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==Keyboard.DOWN || Keyboard.S) {
            down=false;
        }
    }

    private function moveCharacter1(e:Event) {
        if (left) {
            if (platform1.x<1000 && zombie.x==870) {
                platform1.x+=5;
            }
            else {
                if (zombie.x>120) {
                    zombie.x-=zombieSpeed;
                    trace(platform1.x);
                }
            }
        }
        if (right) {
            if (platform1.x>0 && zombie.x==870) {
                platform1.x-=5;
            }
            else {
                if (zombie.x<880) {
                    zombie.x+=zombieSpeed;
                    trace(platform1.x)
                }
            }
        }
        if (jump) {
            goJump();
    }

    function goJump() {
        if(jumpSpeed > 0 && jumpSpeed <= jumpSpeedLimit){
            jumpSpeed *= 1 + jumpSpeedLimit/50;
        }
        zombie.y += jumpSpeed;      
        for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
            if(platform1.hitTestPoint(zombie.x,zombie.y,true)) {
                zombie.y--;
                jumpSpeed=0;
                mainJump=false;
            }
        }
    }

    **private function gamePlay1() {
        if(zombie.hitTestObject(platform1.g1b1)){
            platform1.g1b1.visible = false;
            score+=10;
        }
        if(zombie.hitTestObject(platform1.g1b2)){
            platform1.g1b2.visible = false;
            score+=10;
        }
        if(zombie.hitTestObject(platform1.g1b3)){
            platform1.g1b3.visible = false;
            score+=10;
        }
        if(zombie.hitTestObject(platform1.g1b4)){
            platform1.g1b4.visible = false;
            score+=10;
        }       
   }**

}
```

Comment: zombie.hitTestObject(g1b2)){

Comment: huhu it doesn't work. g1b2 is inside platform1

Comment: If You try trace("platform = " + platform1.toString() + ", brain = " + platform1.g1b1.toString() ); what's the output?

Comment: TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
 at gamePlay1()
 at Game1()
 at frame16()

Comment: @AbbygaleCelineArias that doesn't matter. If it's not working it may be that you have not properly named the brains. You need to check the "export for actionscript" checkbox and make sure to give the brain a name of g1b2 in the linkage name. Do those two things and then my code will work.

Comment: still not working. huhu.
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: g1b2.


Comment: You are only calling your gamePlay1() method in the constructor once. You need to call it in every frame (from your moveCharacter1() method) to check for collisions constantly